# Copy the text value of a referenced categoryfield into another textfield

Tags: php, podio

I have made a webform using the sourcecode from Advanced Webform for Podio . I have a list made from a referenced categoryfield. When an item from the list is selected and the form is submitted, I want the text value from the referenced category field to be copied into the an other textfield.
[image]
After submit and before saving the data into Podio I can fetch the data from the 
post array.

```
if ($_POST){
// all the values are stored in $_POST array
```

Then I get the value from the category field  like this:

```
 $value_from_selected_list = $_POST['uu center'];
```

After this I copy the value to the new text field

```
$_POST['organisation'] = $value_from_selected_list; 
        // set all the values in the Podio app  
       $podioform->set_values($_POST,$_FILES);
       $podioform->save();
       $podioform = 'Kære '.$_POST['navn'].' Tak for din tilmelding';

}
```

My problem is that `$_POST['organisation']` only returns an id and not the text value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. `$_POST['uu-center']`
holds the `item_id` of the referenced app. So I found the `field_id` of the the referenced field  and used the `get_field_value` method that takes the `item_id` and `field_id` as arguments

```
$item_id = $_POST['uu-center'];
$field_id = 154492804;
$uucenter = PodioItem::get_field_value($item_id,$field_id);
```

The method returns an array with the selected value of the field. Then I got the text string.

```
$value_to_be_copy = $uucenter[0][value];
```